# Sendmail for Windows

Tags: windows, email, sendmail

I'm hunting for a mail sending program which can be used with command line arguments.

Ive tried [jaber's](http://www.geocities.com/jaber_aljundi/) sendmail . Its really neat, but its unfortunately broken for SSL auth.

Any alternatives ?

(Oh yeah, I dont want to use perl :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A weird option : You can get the [sendmail.cpp](http://codesuppository.blogspot.com/2008/06/sendmail-send-mail-using-embedded-blat.html) and .h and include in your project. It uses blat internally in a very exotic way.

I was thinking of launching the cmd prompt earlier using ShellExecute(..) to send mails but this is a much more mysterious way of sending mails.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a small PowerShell script:

```
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $body)
```

Values to the function calls must be retrieved from the command line parameters using the $args array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [exim](http://www.exim.org/) under windows by installing [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).  I've used it as an outgoing MTA on windows before.  Pretty sure it has a sendmail facade as well.

Answer (score 1):

As Reno mentions SSL in his question I suggest to keep in mind that Net.Mail.SmtpClient only supports Explicit SSL. In practice you usually will be ok if you use port 587 instead of 465 like your mail client application does. See more details here

[System.Net.Mail with SSL to authenticate against port 465](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdav_101/archive/2008/06/02/system-net-mail-with-ssl-to-authenticate-against-port-465.aspx)